# How to join on none PK/FK columns using HQL?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Using HQL, how do you join on columns (or object properties) that are non PK/FK?

I'm reading the docs, and it seems it implicitly is going to join on the PK columns right?

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html

Comment: In which case would you like to do that ?  Mostly, you'll just wan't to use the relationship that has been defined in the mapping, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

HQL joins "implicitly" on foreign keys. If you don't have a (mapped) relation, just make a cartesian product and join in the where clause.

```
select order.id
from Order as o, Product as p
where o.productKey = p.Key
```

Comment: I see, just wanted to make sure you can do that with HQL.

Answer (score 1):

select order.id 
from Order as o, Product as p 
where o.productKey = p.Key

That would be an inner join, is there a way I can do a left outer using implicit join.